# Why are conformal transformations so relevant?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have been studying construction of initial data in general relativity for many years now and it turns out that the most efficient methods to construct such data rely at some point on conformally changing a background metric (you can look at the conformal method, the conformal thin sandwich... see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.5585).

The idea of conformal transformations is simple: given a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ and a smooth positive function $u$ on $M$, the 2-tensor $u^2 g$ is again a metric on $M$.

There are simple formulas that relate how the various curvatures change under such a conformal transformation. Some of the simplest and most beautiful ones are:

- The Weyl tensor is multiplied by $u^2$ (seen as a fully covariant 4-tensor), i.e. is conformally covariant
- The conformal transformation law for the scalar curvature can be seen as an elliptic equation for $u$ (this is one of the core motivations to study the Yamabe problem).

There are other deformations one can potentially think about such as considering the "graph transformation", namely look at the metric induced on the graph of a given function $f$ in $M \times \mathbb{R}$, i.e. change the metric $g$ to $g + df \otimes df$ (see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.4256). However, formulas appear less appealing from an analytic perspective (for example, ellipticity is not guaranteed).

I would like to understand what makes conformal transformation so relevant among all possible ways to modify a metric.

The beginning of an answer would be that the normalizer of $O(n)$ in $GL(n)$ is the conformal group $CO(n)$. This can be interpreted as saying that two quadratic forms $\Phi_1, \Phi_2$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ have the same orthogonal group, $O(\mathbb{R}^n, \Phi_1) = O(\mathbb{R}^n, \Phi_2)$, if and only if they are proportional one to another. But I do not see how to pass from this remark to the fact that conformal transformations are the nicest ones to consider.

Could you provide further insights or explanations on the connection between the normalizer of $O(n)$ in $GL(n)$ being the conformal group $CO(n)$ and the preference for conformal transformations in modifying a metric? I would appreciate any additional clarification on this topic.

Comment: I opened this post without paying attention to its author, and half way through I decided I want to leave a comment asking the OP to reach out to one of the MO experts on these conformal stuff for his perspective. Yes, I almost left a comment suggesting you to ask Romain Gicquaud...

Comment: Well, one argument is that the spinor Dirac operator on a Riemannian spin manifold is conformally covariant, which implies that various things associated with Dirac operators are conformally invariant, like the dimension of the space of harmonic spinors. I don't know how relevant this is to general relativity, except for a vague awareness of Witten's approach to the positive mass theorem.

Comment: I think the answer is already contained in the 6th paragraph of the post about the "equivalent" quadratic forms. The extension of O(n) by R and the fact that CO(n) is a subgroup of GL(n) could serve to choose the best direction in GL(n) in which one has to deform a given metric. The main issue, from my viewpoint, is how to device the technique helping the choice of that direction. Yang-Mills philosophy can help a much in this regard.

Comment: In *indefinite* pseudo-Riemannian geometry, there's a very concrete reason as to why conformal transformations are important... two indefinite nondegenerate quadratic forms are proportional to each other iff their zero sets coincide. For Lorentzian geometry, this means that conformal transformations preserve light cones; more than that, these are precisely the transformations that preserve the causal structure. This requirement is so strong, that for $n$-dim. strongly causal space-times ($n>2$) any bijection that preserves lightlike geodesic segments must be a *smooth* conformal map.

Comment: @WillieWong: :D

Comment: @PaulSiegel: Indeed, you can generalize your remark to say that all Stein-Weiss operators are conformally covariant.

Comment: @EricArnéoVespiraKengne: I do agree with your remark. However, you get a preferred direction to modify the metric only at the zeroth order jet, while curvature lies at the second order jet. Can you tell me more about the Yang-Mills philosophy? I guess that what you have in mind might be the answer to my question.

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro: This is indeed a very nice observation: conformal compactification lies at the heart of Penrose diagrams. But, my question is more about understanding why conformal transformations are the ones that lead to the nicest curvature transformation laws...

Comment: @RomainGicquaud Well...taking into account the fact you've mentioned in the OP that the conformal group is the normalizer of $O(n)$ in $GL(n)$, remember that from a principal bundle viewpoint the Riemann curvature tensor *of a Riemannian metric* can be seen as a $o(n)$-valued 2-form - more precisely, a 2-form with values in the vector bundle associated with the orthonormal frame bundle whose typical fiber is $o(n)$, so one is dealing with the adjoint action of $O(n)$ therein. This should cause the conformal group to play a special role in how diffeos affect curvature in Riemannian geometry.

Comment: @RomainGicquaud: A metric g define a basis for a direction transverse to O(g) in the frame bundle Fr. That direction determine a canonical real line bundle over O(g), which can be identified with CO(g) and considered as a R-principal bundle over O(g). One can find a metric in the conformal class of g by solving a Yang-Mills-Higgs equations for a weight p, section of CO(g) and a connection 1-form w on CO(g), w naturally extending the Levi-Civita 1-form connection of g. This account for what I understand by Yang-Mills philosophy.

Comment: This can also take care about higher order jets of g, the connection 1-form being some kind of first order deformation. All of this and more can be found in Calderbank and Peterson's "spaces with complex structures, Einstein- Weyl geometry and geodesics" and references therein. Another reason for the preference of conformal for deforming metric, I think, is because SO(n) is a deformation retract of GL(n)+ and so, in pure Riemannian setting, conformal geometry is homotopically, differential geometry..

Comment: @EricArnéoVespiraKengne good point! Another way of seeing this transversality is that you can also see a Riemannian metric $g$ as a "Higgs field" for the reduction of Fr to the orthonormal frame bundle $O(g)$ associated to $g$. Put differently, the smooth Riemannian metrics on $M$ can be identified with the smooth sections of the bundle associated to Fr whose typical fiber is the homogeneous space $GL(n)/O(n)$, and these completely classify all reductions of Fr to principal $O(n)$-bundles over $M$.

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro: you are more than right at the point! So a weight is just a Higgs field. And I want to call a Yang-Mills one, a Morse Hitchin function... This seemingly naive point of view about the conformal factor has a lot of far reaching consequences about geometrisation of manifolds of any dimension and perhaps any regularity, by using in an essential way, Twistor Space Theory, Generalized Seiberg-Witten Theory, Harmonic Analysis (aka variation of Hodge Structures),... There are too many things to do, but I think that the hands needed for the task are still insufficient...